# Create a radio button group per column

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following problem:

I display my data in multiple tables. The tables are dynamically generated and the number of elements can vary. Every row has 4 column's:

- one for "some item"
- one radio-button for x
- one radio-button for y
- one radio-button for z

I want to know if it is possible to group all radio-buttons in each
column. This should work across all tables, so that I get only one value
for every column (the user should only be able to activate one radio-button per column).

In the following you can see an example for my data and the html code.
Or if you want to try it out yourself: 
[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-psq4zb)

I has to work with Angular 5 and Angular-Material.
Thank you in advance.

```js
  data = [
    {
      name: 'foo',
      groups: [
        { name: 'group1', axes: ['some item', 'some item', 'some item'] },
        { name: 'group2', axes: ['some item'] },
        { name: 'group3', axes: ['some item', 'some item'] }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'bar',
      groups: [
        { name: 'group1', axes: ['some item', 'some item'] },
        { name: 'group2', axes: ['some item', 'some item', 'some item'] },
        { name: 'group3', axes: ['some item', ] }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
 <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>

 <div *ngFor="let group of item.groups">
  <strong>{{group.name}}</strong>
  <table border="1">
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>y</td>
    <td>z</td>
   </tr>

   <tr *ngFor="let elem of group.axes">
    <td>{{elem}}</td>
    <td><mat-radio-button></mat-radio-button></td>
    <td><mat-radio-button></mat-radio-button></td>
    <td><mat-radio-button></mat-radio-button></td>
   </tr>

  </table>
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radio buttons are grouped according to their `name` property. In order to group them by column, give the radio buttons a `name` that is specific to each column:

```
<tr *ngFor="let elem of group.axes">
  <td>{{elem}}</td>
  <td><mat-radio-button name="groupX"></mat-radio-button></td>
  <td><mat-radio-button name="groupY"></mat-radio-button></td>
  <td><mat-radio-button name="groupZ"></mat-radio-button></td>
</tr>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dfukey) for a demo.